# Different button style on Apple and Windows systems

Tags: css, button, cross-platform

Can't figure out the way that the button would be shown the same in all systems and browsers, any help?

the screenshots:
https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/550281a9fe2a9b7d36614ec53391db509557c4f9

```
#contactus .container button {
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background-color: #a4cbe3;
border:none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: 2px dashed white;
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
margin-right: 13px; }


<div class='container' id="gavejai">
<button onclick="addfield();" type="button">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers still have some inconsistencies in css rendering, even same version of browser between different operating systems, make sure you defined ALL the css properties of element, which may be different between them. here's the code:

```
#contactus .container button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #a4cbe3;
  border:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 2px dashed white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  margin-right: 13px;

  /* add these styles */
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 35px; /* must be equal to height property */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[edit] I recommend using CSS Reset at the top of your css code which tries to remove this inconsistencies http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/